# Adobe Air URLRequest HTTPS not working

Tags: javascript, https, air, adobe, urlrequest

I am working on an Adobe Air product that fetches data from the web using air.URLRequest, from both HTTP and HTTPS sites. It is working absolutely fine on most computers, but there are a few people for which it is stalling when it has to fetch from HTTPS sites.

The error returned is just this: ERROR #2032 Stream Error. Doesn't say much.

I asked the people who had the problem to install Fiddler so that i can debug it and activate HTTPS decryption, but there is no way to debug because it works when Fiddler is open.

The application is built using JavaScript, HTML and CSS and the PC's with the problems are using either Windows Vista or Windows 7. I am also using Windows 7 but it's working fine for me.

Any idea how i could fix this very weird issue ?

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Can they open the target urls in their browsers without error?  You can code all sorts of error checking.

Comment: Did you try to set a crossdomain.xml file in the root? (more info here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000469.html)